# How do I delete post fetched from Firebase using a button by a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I successfully fetched posts from Firebase and those data were displayed via looping on the page like this:

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l6" id="KQlQlg_Vg6eVWDI19NM">
  <div>
    <span class="modify-post"><span class="edit btn green waves-effect waves-light" title="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></span>
    <span id="KQlQlg_Vg6eVWDI19NM" class="delete btn red waves-effect waves-light" title="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span>
    </span><span class="post_tag"> Birthday </span>
    <h3 class="post_title">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <div class="post_short">
      <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem </p>
    </div><button class="blue btn waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i> &nbsp; View post </button>
    <p class="post-details white-text"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So each post's `<div>` have an id equal to the id of its post in Firebase. Now the problem I have is in a verge to delete a post via the delete button I created. It doesn't return anything nor delete any post for me from the database.

Here is my attempt to implement that:

```
function deletePost(postId) {
  var sure = confirm("are you sure to delete this post?");
  if (sure) {
    firebase.database().ref('blog/').child('posts/' + postId).remove().then(function() {
      alert("post deleted!");
    });
  } else {
    alert("Something happened, couldn't delete post. Please try again");
  }
}

$('span.modify-post>span.delete').click(function(e) {
  var clickedPostId = e.target.offsetParent.id;
  alert("you just clicked the post with id " + clickedPostId);
  deletePost(clickedPostId);
});
```

Appreciate any help.

**PS (*from comments section*)**:
The JavaScript code works when I paste it to the console, but it won't work when it's in the HTML or its JavaScript file

Comment: the javascript code works when I paste it to console but it won't work when it's in the html or its Javascript file

Answer (score 0):

You have to render your click event after the HTML load

```
<div class="col s12 m6 l6" id="KQlQlg_Vg6eVWDI19NM">
  <div>
    <span class="modify-post"><span class="edit btn green waves-effect waves-light" title="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></span>
    <span id="KQlQlg_Vg6eVWDI19NM" class="delete btn red waves-effect waves-light" title="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></span>
    </span><span class="post_tag"> Birthday </span>
    <h3 class="post_title">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
    <div class="post_short">
      <p>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit ametlorem </p>
    </div><button class="blue btn waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-align-left"></i> &nbsp; View post </button>
    <p class="post-details white-text"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
ClickEvent();
<script>
function ClickEvent(){
$('span.modify-post>span.delete').click(function(e) {
  var clickedPostId = e.target.offsetParent.id;
  alert("you just clicked the post with id " + clickedPostId);
  deletePost(clickedPostId);
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I couldn't delete my [firebase](http://firebase.google.com) post on click event is because my code runs immediately after document finish loading and not when firebase is done fetching post from [database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). So to correct this, I can either use `$(window).load()` event handler(in case of jQuery) or `window.onload()` (for pure javascript) in order to ensure firebase loads my data to the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) (using my functions) before it carry out any [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) based operation.

Here is my solution:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  $('span.modify-post>span.delete').click(function (e) {
    var clickedPostId = e.target.offsetParent.id;
    alert("you just clicked the post with id " + clickedPostId);
    // deletePost(clickedPostId);
    var sure = confirm("are you sure to delete this post?");
    if (sure) {
      firebase.database().ref('blog/').child('posts/' + clickedPostId).remove().then(function () {
        alert("post deleted!");
      });
    }
  });
});
```